# Undo babel-swedish's redefinition of \-

Tags: babel, hyphenation

`babel-swedish` redefines `\-` so that it allows hyphenation in the rest of the word. To me, this seems ill-advised. How can I undo this in my preamble?

The redefinition is done as below:

```
\addto\extrasswedish{\babel@save\-}
\addto\extrasswedish{\def\-{\allowhyphens
\discretionary{-}{}{}\allowhyphens}}
```

A minimal document that shows the behavior could be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\textwidth=1pt
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
  xxx general\-sekreterare
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than remove the part from `\extrasswedish`, you can *override* it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\textwidth=1pt
\parindent=0pt

\NewCommandCopy{\latexdiscretionary}{\-}
\addto\extrasswedish{\RenewCommandCopy{\-}{\latexdiscretionary}}

\begin{document}

xxx general\-sekreterare

\end{document}
```

[image]